# Javascript Craps Game Simulation Unhandled Error?

Tags: javascript, html

I was testing out javascript games and functions and on this particular example it keeps getting stuck after clicking on the play button, after I inspected the elements of the source code it showed me that error is in the two functions pasted below, however I dont know why are these exceptions given , any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    function rollDice()
        {
            dicerolling.play();

            die1Value = NaN;
            die2Value = NaN;
            showDice();

            die1Value = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
            die2Value = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 6);
            return die1Value + die2Value;
        }

        function showDice()
        {
            setImage( rollDie1Img, die1Value );
            setImage( rollDie2Img, die2Value );
        }

        function setImage( dieImg, dieValue )
        {
            if ( isFinite ( dieValue ) )
                dieImg.src = "images//" + dieValue + ".png";
            else
                dieImg.src = "images//blank.png";
        }
```

the complete code is pasted here if needed :

http://codepaste.net/o29v92

the error given by chrome :

[image: chrome error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same ID twice in your  elements:

```
<img id="rollDie1" src = "images/blank.png" alt = "Die 1 of Roll Value">
<img id="rollDie1" src = "images/blank.png" alt = "Die 1 of Roll Value">
```

Judging from your code, you should just use `rollDie2` for the second one:

```
<img id="rollDie1" src="images/blank.png" alt="Die 1 of Roll Value">
<img id="rollDie2" src="images/blank.png" alt="Die 2 of Roll Value">
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Waa/)

Comment: oh wow I spent so much time but only at the script section , should pay more attention on the body part , thank you so much for pointing it out, but I must admit these things sure do make me confused sometimes

Comment: @Rage91 No worries, I used console.log() to track what was dieImg was and noticed that it was working for the first time but not the second, that's why I went to the HTML